# Linking to .so residing in AAR dependency library package

Tags: android-ndk, aar

I have native .so libs packaged into `AAR`. This `AAR` package is added from `remote repository`. App's `NDK build` requires linking of `.so from AAR`.

How to specify the path in `App's Android.mk` to link to pre-built .so in AAR package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no straight forward way of doing this. This requires gradle task which sync `AAR` package from repository and then extract the binaries to appropriate locations in the application.

Comment: Google have done it the ArCore for C, but I couldn't get it work